# 120 V 9000 BTU mini split from sub panel and wire info

Tags: electrical, wiring

I am adding a mini split from the sub  panel of my home to additional room I am adding . Mini split of 120 v, 9000 btu and 20 Ampacity. From panel to disconnect fuse box,my contractor installed 8/3 ( 8 gauge??) wire but mini split require 20 amp ( 20 ampacity) which should be Ok with 12 or 10 gauge wire. Is it ok to connect the this mini split with this 8 gauge wire to pass Vito inspection ? Wire length may be 20 ft.

Comment: The only problem should be if the device connections are not made for(does not fit) or marked for 8 gauge.

Answer (score 5):

Using the larger size wire will be OK. Make sure to use a 20 amp breaker or whatever the instructions call for. If the breaker or mini split connections won't handle the #8 AWG wire, use wire nuts and splice a piece of #12 or #10 to the #8 and connect the smaller wire to the devices

Comment: Thanks .. is there any city code or national rules or code link I can read for more details ?

Comment: @Zia you haven't specified which city or country you're in, so ...

Comment: The NEC is sometimes difficult to read even for professionals. Try this: http://wiresizecalculator.net/   It will show you that the #8 wire chosen by your contractor is well over the minimum size for your usage.

Comment: Wires can **always be larger than required for the current** (but you may need to join to smaller wires depending on device terminal largest capacity - or not.)

Comment: @Zia NEC 250.122(B). It specifically authorizes using larger wire than needed, *but* it specifies the ground wire being enlarged in proportion.  On paper that would require #8 ground, but if you read the Handbook *for the reason* for the rule, it clearly does not apply here, and the AHJ should waive it.  (the reason is that if you're enlarging hot wires to reduce voltage drop on a Very Long Run, you want ground to be able to flow enough current to trip the breaker.)

Comment: Thanks ,.. but 8/3 wire should have same dia wire for all three wire ?